# Microservice Architecture intra cluster communication

Tags: architecture, microservices

Usually teams use rest apis to communicate from microservice A to B, but that means tight coupling which is something that should be avoided if possible. Also, if there's a dependency from A to B, and B is down, not only it is desirable not to fail the original request to A, but also the request information should not be lost.
Another way to do this should be queueing. But:

- if B is down, then A won't be available to answer anyway;
- even if the request information is in the queue, when B comes up there's no way to process the request, get back the response to A and back to the client;
- when there's only 2 nodes, there's only need for at most 2 queues (one for each way), but when we're dealing with 12 microservices, creating a queue for each communication needs between all those nodes easily becomes impractical.

**Finally the question**: what am I missing? Can you point me to some reading that answers to this question clearly, possibly with an example?

P.S. I'm looking at spring boot atm to develop my microservices, some pointers in this context would be appreciated, but not essential.

Comment: Your assumptions are too much strict. Rest API are good.
"... and B is down, not only it is desirable not fail the original request to A ..." it depends on what the request is.
Queueing is not always needed.  
I would suggest you to read about Domain Driven Design to have an idea of architectures. These kind of issues are not related to the technology used, but more to abstract properties of what you are doing (the domain).  
Being microservice or a monolith doesn't imply that you have to use a queue or not, it is the what you are doing that tells you.

Answer (score 0):

The aspects you mentioned are general concerns/downsides of a microservice-based architecture. If you have requirements which are orthogonal with those aspects, then you should choose a different approach, maybe a service-based architecture.

AFAIK, for business flows which involve critical user interaction (e.g. authentication), *ideally you should have a single microservice which handles that flow*. In this way you minimize the dependency overhead of other microservices, which involve resiliency-related aspects (like the ones mentioned above), that may become problematic when things go wrong:

- Having timeouts
- Retry policies
- Queuing, as you mentioned (to avoid data loss)
- Circuit breaking

That doesn't mean you can't have multiple microservices on that critical path, but the more you increase the length of that path, the more it becomes challenging to handle a real-time flow.

[Here](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) is a great website around microservices architecture.